# Bibliography with typeset engine change

Tags: bibliographies, xetex

I changed my typeset engine almost at the end of my thesis from pdfLaTex to XeLaTex.

Unsurprisingly, it messed up the bibliography I already set up.

I know that I should make one latex run, one biblatex run and then one/two latex run again with my main file name following, however I would like a couple of clarifications about it:

is this code correct? (the name of the file is Cattolica.tex)

```
latex Cattolica
bibtex Cattolica
latex Cattolica
latex Cattolica
```

or I should type xelatex instead of latex?

My bib package is \usepackage{apacite} this means I'm using biblatex or biber (and change the code before accordingly?)?

Thanks

Comment: You have to use xelatex if you want to use. Depending on the biblatex options, you need to run Biber *or* BibTeX. All this in a terminal or command line. Or set up your editor to do it for you.

Comment: I'm using terminal (Macbook) but it doesn't find my file name, neither "Cattolica" nor "Cattolica.tex"

Comment: "This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `Cattolica'.
<*> Cattolica
             
"

Comment: You need to `cd` to the right directory.

Comment: if you are using `apacite` you are not using biblatex.

Comment: Is there any news here?